# Would Aroden's Spellbane prevent True Sight's effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I'm familiar with the debate on True Sight vs. Mind Blank. I'm also aware that tensions run high on both sides, but for this question to apply, I must make the following assumption: by GM ruling, True Sight is able to perceive invisible subjects with Mind Blank active.

Imagine a caster of an arbitrary class able to cast the following three spells: Aroden's Spellbane, Greater Invisibility, and Mind Blank.

Greater Invisibility is fairly straight-forward and was previously cast in-combat. Mind Blank has been active all day (24 hour duration). Aroden's Spellbane is cast, choosing arbitrary spells that do NOT include Greater Invisibility or Mind Blank and one of which IS True Sight.

The caster then faces someone or something capable of True Sight in one of the forms affected by Anti-Magic Field, but outside of the range of Aroden's Spellbane such that it is not automatically dispelled.

Can the someone or something with True Sight perceive the caster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True seeing affects the creature it is cast upon. The target is "creature touched" and the language in the spell description all refers to what the target can do. If the target of true seeing is outside the radius of spellbane, the two spells do not interact, and true seeing would function normally.